# Mongoose Not Saving Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having trouble with a simple query on my database. Following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4 when Model.find() is called, he receives a JSON object back with the name field (the only custom field) and the _id and __v. When I do the same, all I receive back is the _id and __v field. I do get a successful response back saying the post was created, but it doesn't include the title or content fields. Yet a query shows that the data was never saved.

Routing and query:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var Post = require("../app/models/post.js");

/* Drop Post collection
Post.remove({}, function(err, num_docs) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Collection dropped, documents deleted: " + num_docs);
    }
});
*/

// Middleware for all routes.
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("API request made.");
    next(); // Go to next routes, don't stop here
});

// Test route to ensure routing is working
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        message: "Hooray! Welcome to the API!"
    });
});

// On routes that end in /posts
router.route("/posts")
    // Create post. (Accessed at POST http://localhost/api/posts)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var post = new Post(); // Create new instance of post model

        post.title = req.body.title; // Set title (from request)
        post.content = req.body.content; // Set content (from request)

        // Save the post, and check for errors.
        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json({
                    message: "Post created!",
                    title: post.title,
                    content: post.content
                });
            }
        });
    })

    .get(function(req, res) {
        Post.find({}).exec(function(err, posts) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json(posts);
            }

        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "56a6adc31f06c4dc1cf82888",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "56a9768888f806dc1fe45415",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "56a97f3f4e269b7c21311df8",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

A db query in the shell returns the same information, just an _id and __v field.

Comment: Why `Post.remove({});` is called before `Post.find()`?

Comment: That was just some testing. I was trying to delete the collection before it started getting huge from me testing post operations over and over. It doesn't work though, how do I drop a collection when I never even made a collection. When I run post.save() what collection is it getting stored in?

Comment: `how do I drop a collection when I never even made a collection.`? if there is no collection, why dope it?

Comment: Given you connect to `test` db in your connection string. after `post.save()`. the `post` collection should be found under `test` db..

Comment: Okay, just saw your new post. So why does post.remove({}) not delete them all? And back to my main question, why is the query not returning any fields?

Comment: `User.remove({}, function(err){
  if (err)
   console.log(err);
  else
   console.log('success delete ');
 });` could work well in my local test. it can delete all record in the user document

Comment: As for the `find`, have you check your db that all Post data are correct in db?

Comment: side note:  before you do post.save() make sure to check if the item already exists in the database to avoid duplication

Comment: db.posts.find() returns the same as the output. So the data isn't saving I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I am beyond confused right now. It suddenly works, the code is the exact same as above. I am going to leave this open in case someone stumbles across it one day and can solve this mystery.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to set the `content-type` while sending the post request as `application/json` otherwise the fields are not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced an error like this.

The problem was that I was loading the wrong mongoose Schema.

The result is that the only fields that are saved are those that are present in both schemas, i.e. `_id` and `__v`.

Answer (score 0):

For this code

`post.title = req.body.title; // Set title (from request)
post.content = req.body.content; // Set content (from request)`

could you check

1. `req.body.title` and `req.body.content` are not `undefined`?
2. do you set the field in your Post schema as

   var PostSchema = new Schema({
      title: String, 
      content: String 
   });

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a manual tool like Postman to test your app, you must also put quotes around the key names in the body of your request, like `{"key": "some string"}`.

If you just put `{key: "some string"}` then the whole key/value pair is ignored when the document is saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same thing happened to me...

First two POSTs succeeded but did not post the data I was sending:

```
var p = new Post();
p.result = 'hello-world';

p.save(function (err) {});
```

Turned on debug mode: `mongoose.set('debug', true);` and next POST the field was saved...

Baffling!