# Mongoose Saving Incorrect Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When creating an object from a post request, both of the fields that come from the request body are being set to the field name itself. I am not getting any errors but I am also not getting the expected JSON object of the request body back in the response. I was using a local mongodb instance but now I am using a mongolab database, thought it would maybe solve the problem but nothing changed.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var Post = require("../app/models/post.js");

/*
//Drop Post collection
Post.remove({}, function(err, num_docs) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Collection dropped, documents deleted: " + num_docs);
    }
});
*/

// Middleware for all routes.
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("API request made.");
    next(); // Go to next routes, don't stop here
});

// Test route to ensure routing is working
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        message: "Hooray! Welcome to the API!"
    });
});

// On routes that end in /posts
router.route("/posts")
    // Create post. (Accessed at POST http://localhost/api/posts)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        var post = new Post(); // Create new instance of post model

        if (req.body.title !== undefined) {
            post.title = req.body.title; // Set title (from request)
        }
        if (req.body.content !== undefined) {
            post.content = req.body.content; // Set content (from request)
        }

        // Save the post, and check for errors.
        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json(req.body);
            }
        });

    })

    .get(function(req, res) {
        Post.find({}, { "__v": 0, "_id": 0 }).exec(function(err, posts) {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                res.json(posts);
            }

        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Request JSON:

```
{
    "title": "sample title",
    "content": "sample content"
}
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "lastUpdated": "2016-01-29T07:26:01.810Z",
        "uploadDate": "2016-01-29T07:26:01.810Z",
        "content": "content",
        "title": "title"
    }
]
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific than *'not getting expected result"*. You need to show what you are sending and what you expect to see. You also seem to imply this has changed only since changing a database connection string. In which case, if this works on a local instance but not remote, then permissions are your likely issue here. Really unclear which part is not working for you. The "GET" or the "POST"? Needs clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I added the output and request.

Comment: Changing databases from local to remote didn't change anything. And by not getting the expected JSON object of the request I mean `res.json(req.body)` returned an empty JSON object as the response. But the content and title fields should be based off the request JSON, but they're not.

Comment: @Jordan Are you using an HTML form with name attributes to get the data? Are you having problems getting that data into a JSON object?

Comment: No, I am just using postman to test my API. I'm sending the json to my api route which has the get and post methods above. I have no idea why this is not working and I'm about to switch to SQL. I literally can't find a solution anywhere and nobody has the same problem, I've tried every alternative and the same thing just keeps happening.

Comment: If you see my previous post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051953/mongoose-not-saving-data this somehow magically fixed itself. None of the code changed and it started working and then same thing here but opposite. None of the code changed and it stopped working, no more response from the post request. I am having the strangest problems with mongoose and mongodb. I've never experienced anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use req.body without including body parser and expect req.body to produce the expected result in express. Did you do `npm install body-parser`. I don't see you requiring `body-parser` in your code. Maybe you included [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) in your main file. I believe that if you don't use it req.body will be empty.

add this below your other requires

`var bodyParser = require("body-parser");`

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));`

`app.use(bodyParser.json())`

and don't forget to do `npm install body-parser` in your terminal.

Comment: I do have all of this in my main file, app.js. Is there anything specific I must include in the responses to parse it? Like do I have to do `res.json(bodyParser.someFunction(req.body)));`?

Comment: res.json({req.body}) or  res.send(req.body)

Comment: Neither worked, the same thing still happens. Not to mention it isn't saving the correct data either. And `res.json({req.body})` throws a syntax error for unexpected token and points to the `.` in `req.body`