# Mongo api POST with missing fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mean-stack

The fields in my JSON object are not being inserted by Mongo on an api call. I think I'm misunderstanding what the object in the JSON test data needs to be named. I've tried very combination of "ToDo", "todo" etc, but to no avail.

I'm attempting this [tutorial for building a MEAN stack app](https://medium.com/netscape/mean-app-tutorial-with-angular-4-part-1-18691663ea96). I've managed to build it, however, using this JSON object in the body of a Postman POST test call

```
"todo": {
    title: "TaskTitle",
    description: "TaskDescription",
    status: "Not assigned"
}
```

when I come to test by POSTing in Postman, only the `_id`, `date` and `__v` fields are populated when I view the newly created object in Robo 3T.

I was expecting to see `_id`, `date`, `__v`, `title`, `description` and `status` populated in Robo 3T.

My model looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate')


var ToDoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    date: Date,
    status: String
})

ToDoSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)
const ToDo = mongoose.model('Todo', ToDoSchema)

module.exports = ToDo;
```

and the controller that does the posting itself shows the request body to be undefined viz;

```
exports.createTodo = async function(req, res, next){
    // Req.Body contains the form submit values.
    console.log(toString(req.body.title));//----shows as [object Undefined] in console
    var todo = {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        status: req.body.status
    }

    try{

        // Calling the Service function with the new object from the Request Body

        var createdTodo = await TodoService.createTodo(todo)
        return res.status(201).json({status: 201, data: createdTodo, message: "Succesfully Created ToDo"})
    }catch(e){
```

I've tried [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051953/mongoose-not-saving-data), but to no avail....

Comment: Are you using Express?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid JSON:

```
"todo": {
    title: "TaskTitle",
    description: "TaskDescription",
    status: "Not assigned"
}
```

These are:

```
{
    "todo": {
        title: "TaskTitle",
        description: "TaskDescription",
        status: "Not assigned"
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    title: "TaskTitle",
    description: "TaskDescription",
    status: "Not assigned"
}
```

Comment: What output do you get from `console.log(req.body);`

Comment: console.log(toString(req.body.title));//----shows as [object Undefined] in console

Comment: That's not the same line: `console.log(req.body);`

Comment: console.log(req.body); gives [object Object]

Comment: That's weird, but we are getting close. And ` 
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));` ?

Comment: thanks so much for sticking with me...problem was was using Postman to test and had the body format as "Text", not "JSON (application/json)"

Problem resolved...wah!

Answer (score 0):

@MondKin thanks so much for sticking with me...problem was  was using Postman to test and had the body format as "Text", not "JSON (application/json)"

Problem resolved...wah!